# MacBook Pro becomes terribly Slow When Using The Secondary GPU

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

Whenever mac starts to use the secondary GPU (AMD Radeon), such as graphical tasks or when I use a secondary display, It becomes terribly slow.

I can say that it must be a GPU problem because if I disable GPU switching from Battery preferences, it starts to become slower.

This problem occurred after the day I run a high-graphics game (CS:GO). Can this damage the GPU?

Are there any solutions that I can try?

Comment: Please give us more details about your problem. Describe what exactly is "slow", what model MacBook Pro and version of macOS are you using and trouble shooting steps you've already tried (such as trying another user, PRAM reset, booting from another volume, etc.)

Comment: I am using Macbook Pro 2019 16''. By slow I mean I meant it responses slowly to my actions and I get a very low fps on any graphical task. I've tried resetting PRAM/NVRAM.

Comment: If you have an external drive around you could try installing macOS and booting from it. If the issue persists I'd contact Apple or take it to a Service Provider to run a hardware test.

Comment: PS: Running a high-graphics game can not damage the GPU unless there is something wrong with the machine, there are temperature sensors making sure that the fans move enough air to keep the machine at acceptable temperature or shut down if really necessary.